# How to move a user into a group by user_id

Tags: 14.04

I don't know username but i know user_id, so How can i move that user into a group ?

Example, i know a user with user_id = 5000, and i want to move that user into group abc.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On a single occasion or more often?

Comment: On a single occasion

Comment: There must be a better solution, but if you run `cat /etc/passwd`, you can see a list of all users. Lines are divided in sections, separated with ":". 1st item is user name, third is uid. look up uid in the third "column" and you will have the username.

Comment: ... or even `getent passwd 5000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As root, you can find the username with:

```
getent passwd 5000
```

It will return something like this:

```
username:x:5000:5000:...
```

The first field is the username. To add to the abc group, do this:

```
adduser username abc
```

Comment: No need to be root at all.